# Invalid Input Syntax for Integer in Filtering Empty Values

Tags: postgresql

I have a transaction table and I want to filter the empty userid.

My query looks like this in pgadmin:

```
SELECT
USER_ID,
POSTED_AT
FROM TRANSACTIONS
WHERE USER_ID <> ''
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

I got an error message like `invalid input syntax for integer: ""`
How can I fix it?

Comment: @ivan , `null` and empty are different. `null` can't be checked like that.

Comment: try this. `SELECT USER_ID, POSTED_AT FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE USER_ID IS NOT NULL ORDER BY 2 DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You can't check an `INT` field that way `WHERE USER_ID <> ''` since it's not a `VARCHAR` type column. Posted error message saying the exact same thing *invalid input syntax for **integer*** You may want to check

```
WHERE USER_ID IS NOT NULL
AND USER_ID > 0
```